# Signature field not showing in docusign template in recipient side

Tags: docusignapi

I have created new templated and added a document. after that I added signature field with few text fields.After sent it in recipient side when viewing it's only showing those text fields.
What can be the issue here?

Previously I have created another template and in recipient side completed it.After that this issue happening I guess.

please help me what to do

Answer (score 0):

Next step to debug is to get an [API Log](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) for your API calls.

Also check that you have specified the `role` names in your API call to **exactly** match the role names in your template.

If you can't spot the error, then EDIT your question to add the API log.

Comment: I think login only can enable in pro accounts.Now I'm using testing account.
After that I have created another new docusign test account and tried to request signature, in that template also not showing signature field

Comment: Logging works in production and developer (demo) accounts. Please open a new stackoverflow question and include your request's API log.